# Symfony - belongsTo in same entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony-3.4

I want to have direct relation between two entity fields from same table.

The idea is to add in my entity manager_id, which will point to another user in user table (I tried with OneToOne.

When user calls the action, user_id to whom to, for example, send the message will be pulled as

> $user->getManager()->getId();

Error log says:

**No mapping found for field ID.**

```
class User  
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", 
      mappedBy="id")
    */
   private $manager;
```

Comment: That's called self-reference. There are examples in Doctrine ORM documentation. And I think you want `One-To-Many` relation, instead of `One-To-One`. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to create such relation is to use undirectional relation type. Code for it looks like this:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     protected $id;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     */
     private $manager;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
/** @var User $user */
$managerId = $user->getManager()->getId();
```

Hope this helps.

PS. I added some @var docblocks for hinting.

Comment: I did it the same as you. Thanks a lot for help. @IgorW.